# How to Create PCKE Url with auth

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth

I have a web login url. I need to reproduce this url in accordance with PCKE and get the authorization code when logged in. In this case, I can understand the stages, but I did not fully understand how to convert these stages into code. How to create a PCKE proper url and make it work? How can I capture the authorization code after the login is provided? Can anyone with experience in this area help me out?